# Geoquery to populate a ListView/RecyclerView

Tags: android, listview, firebase, android-recyclerview, geofire

I'm developing an Android App with Firebase as a backend.
So far it worked very smoothly and I loved it, but now I encountered a major roadblock.
The app has to search for deals around a certain location and then populate a `ListView` (or a `RecyclerView`) accordingly.
I've already included Geofire in my Firebase structure, having a main **deals** node and a **geofire** node with the same keys, and the Geoquery is returning them fine.

My problem is that the `FirebaseListAdapter` that I've grabbed from the Firebase examples doesn't have a single item add method, that it's what I'll need as the Geoquery will return only one key at time.
After a long search, I've haven't been able to find an example of code that was dealing with the same issue, so I would like to ask for some advice on how, and which is the most efficient way to implement this.

Thanks

P.S.: my firebase structure:

```
{
  "deals" : {
    "-JikH6yjJ9TblE8_4fX4" : {
      "category" : "Food",
      "description" : "example description",
      "location" : "George St, Brisbane",
      "title" : "some title",
    }
  },
  "geofire" : {
    "-JikH6yjJ9TblE8_4fX4" : {
      ".priority" : "r7hgf2d639",
      "g" : "r7hgf2d639",
      "l" : [ -27.46268003, 153.03172851 ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to populate Android ListView with information from Firebase query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414344/how-to-populate-android-listview-with-information-from-firebase-query)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`FirebaseListAdapter` will only work for the simple case where you want to add *all* children from a Firebase location into a list. It is intended as a simple helper class. With more complicated examples like this, you will need to write your own `ListAdapter`.

After receiving a key entered event for your `GeoQuery` you can add a value listener for the actual values in the `deals` node. You can then use those value events to populate and update your list view.

Make sure to remove the value listener(s) on a key exit event or when you dispose of the list view.

Comment: I solved momentarily, fetching the .json key element and parsing it in the list as a object at it works, even if it's quite slow.

Comment: I actually tried to use the `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` and it's way faster and more efficient. Thanks @jonnydee

Comment: @ymerdrengene I wasn't checking out that code in a while, but I've been able to extract it in a gist for you (actually 2). [ExampleFragment](https://gist.github.com/emanuelet/b8c0049fc29702bc2fdbd493b385e7b2) and [ListAdapter](https://gist.github.com/emanuelet/38f490bdbb4b7b91f183)

Comment: @EmanueleTonello Thank you, it looks awesome :) In ExampleFragment.java what kind of Adapter are you using? The one that says ItemListAdapter.

Comment: @ymerdrengene I rename it to make it generic, but is in second gist that I attached to message with the Adapter and the abstract class

Comment: @EmanueleTonello I tried your newly added  ExampleAdapter (https://gist.github.com/emanuelet/38f490bdbb4b7b91f183#file-exampleadapter-java) and it worked :) I can now display a ListView with a GeoFire query. Thank you!